# Create a nested data dictionary in Python

Tags: python, data-dictionary

I have the data as below

```
{
  "employeealias": "101613177", 
  "firstname": "Lion", 
  "lastname": "King", 
  "date": "2022-04-21", 
  "type": "Thoughtful Intake", 
  "subject": "Email: From You Success Coach"
}

{
  "employeealias": "101613177", 
  "firstname": "Lion",
  "lastname": "King",
  "date": "2022-04-21",
  "type": null,
  "subject": "Call- CDL options & career assessment"
}
```

I need to create a dictionary like the below:

[image]

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create new dictionary with list and use `for`-loop to check if exists `employeealias`, `firstname`, `lastname` to add other information to sublist. If item doesn't exist then you have to create new item with `employeealias`, `firstname`, `lastname` and other information.

```
data = [
{"employeealias":"101613177","firstname":"Lion","lastname":"King","date":"2022-04-21","type":"Thoughtful Intake","subject":"Email: From You Success Coach"},
{"employeealias":"101613177","firstname":"Lion","lastname":"King","date":"2022-04-21","type":"null","subject":"Call- CDL options & career assessment"},
]

result = {'interactions': []}

for row in data:
    found = False
    for item in result['interactions']:
        if (row["employeealias"] == item["employeealias"]
           and row["firstname"] == item["firstname"]
           and row["lastname"] == item["lastname"]):
            item["activity"].append({
               "date": row["date"],
               "subject": row["subject"],
               "type": row["type"],
            })
            found = True
            break
        
    if not found:
        result['interactions'].append({
            "employeealias": row["employeealias"],
            "firstname": row["firstname"],
            "lastname": row["lastname"],
            "activity": [{
                           "date": row["date"],
                           "subject": row["subject"],
                           "type": row["type"],
                        }]
        })
            
print(result)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You read lines as normal text but you have to convert text to dictonary using module json

```
import json

data = [] 

with open("/Users/Downloads/amazon_activity_feed_0005_part_00.json") as a_file:      
    for line in a_file:         
        line = line.strip()
        dictionary = json.loads(line)         
        data.append(dictionary)

print(data)
```

Comment: thank you so much @furas. you made my day today. appreciate your quick response.

Comment: I have the data in a file and I tried making data list similar to what you have done but giving an error    "employeealias": row["employeealias"],
TypeError: string indices must be integers

`data = []
with open("/Users/Downloads/amazon_activity_feed_0005_part_00.json","rt") as a_file:
     for line in a_file:
        data.appen(line)
        print(data)`

Comment: you read lines as normal text but you have to convert text to dictonary using module `json` and `dictionary = json.loads(line)`, `data.append(dictionary)`. I added example to answer.

Comment: perfection again. !!! Wish , one day I can program like you!  Thank you so much @furas.

Comment: When the data in the file grows, does this hit performance? should I re-engineer this in spark or pandas? does they help?

Comment: you would have to measure time for bigger data to see if you really have to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a nested dictionary inside Python like this:
`student = {name : "Suman", Age = 20, gender: "male",{class : 11, roll no: 12}}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).